# How to set Jetty Request Log to default Timezone using XML

Tags: java, logging, jetty, jetty-9

I am not able to make Jetty Request-log log requests with the local time-zone time using the following code,

```
   <Set name="LogTimeZone" type="java.lang.String">
       <Get class="java.util.TimeZone" name="default">
           <Get name="ID"/>
        </Get>
    </Set>
```

it defaults to GMT. The setLogTimeZone() (http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.9.v20160517/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.html#setLogTimeZone-java.lang.String-) accepts a string argument and therefore should ideally work. But, it doesn't! Although, when providing the required String directly it works just fine,

```
  <Set name="LogTimeZone">Europe/London</Set>
```

the jetty log(std error) seems to be working fine. Is this a known bug?

**Jetty Version used : 9.1.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the result of `getID()` out of the `TimeZone.getDefault()` into an xml `id` attribute, then reference it later in the `<Set>` call using a `<Ref>` element.

Example of how this works in Jetty XML:

**foo.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" 
                           "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure id="foo" class="java.lang.Object">
  <Get class="java.util.TimeZone" name="default">
    <Get id="defaultTimeZone" name="ID"/>
  </Get>
  <Get id="sysout" class="java.lang.System" name="out">
    <Call name="println">
      <Arg>
        <Ref refid="defaultTimeZone"/>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Get>
</Configure>
```

Testing it on the command line ...

```
$ cd /path/to/jetty-dist-9.3.9.v20160517/
$ java -cp lib/jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:lib/jetty-xml-9.3.9.v20160517.jar \
  org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration foo.xml
2016-07-13 17:16:25.447:INFO::main: Logging initialized @121ms
America/Phoenix
```

Comment: Worked! thanks :)..But, why this hack? doesn't my code translate into `myNCSARequestLog.setLogTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());`. Or is my understanding wrong?